# multilevel Debug using c preprocessor macros

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have excerpts of code for a multi-level debug implementation, which I don't know how to make it work.

I have tried some of the suggestions posted here about using the do {...} while (0), and I also tried to declare a global variable called Debug, but none of them seem to work.

What should I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//#define DEBUG(fmt, ...)  fprintf (stderr, fmt, __VA_ARGS__ )

#ifdef DEBON
    #define DEBUG(level, fmt, ...) \
        if (Debug >= level) \
            fprintf (stderr, fmt, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
    #define DEBUG(level, fmt, ...)
#endif

int process ( int i1, int i2)
{
    int val;

    DEBUG (1, "process (%i, %i)\n", i1, i2);
    val = i1 * i2;
    DEBUG (3, "return %i\n", val);

    return val;
}

int main ( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arg1 = 0, arg2 = 0;
    if (argc > 1)
        arg1 = atoi (argv[1]);
    if ( argc == 3)
        arg2 = atoi (argv[2]);

    DEBUG (1, "processed %i arguments\n", argc -1 );
    DEBUG (3, "arg1 = %i, arg2 = %i\n" , arg1, arg2);
    printf ("%d\n", process (arg1, arg2));

    return 0;
}
```

Below is a simpler file I put together to see if I can get this working. No luck yet.

```
#define DEBUG(level, fmt, ...) if (Debug >= level ) fprintf (stderr, fmt, __VA_ARGS__)
#include <stdio.h>
int Debug;
int main()
{
int i1 = 1;
int i2 = 2;
DEBUG(3, "process (%i, %i)\n", i1, i2);

}
```

Comment: You should copy the enum containing the definition of Debug from the original source.

Comment: I don't have anything else aside from what I shared. I just know that the way it is supposed to work is by executing the program with the -d option and specifying the debug level desired. i.e. a.out -d3 would provide the most verbose. I can not figure out how this value is passed to the code as Debug value and why it is not working in my case.

Comment: The option you cited (-d3) actually specifies how much debug information to be included in the executable file. Such information is accessible when you use a debugger. What you want instead is -DDebug=3

Comment: Thanks. I am doing something wrong. I tried your suggestion on the code I put together above, and a smaller more simple file, which I'll post in the main body of the message. No go:-(

Comment: *none of them seem to work* is not a useful problem description.  You need to tell us *what* doesn't work, *how* it "doesn't work", and how you want it to work.

Comment: Thanks. What does not work is the functionality of being able to specify at run time a desired level of debug, given a number of them. If I understand correctly, one should not have to recompile in order to do this. This is how Linux Kernel Building is setup. At least that is my interpretation of it. I am just trying to understand how they did it with a simpler example. Oh; I'll do a much better job of documenting what did not work. The issue may be how I phrased the question; I thought I captured what I tried. I'll make it more detailed next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You last example works after minor tweaks. The idea in the book is to have your program parse the command line options and set the value of a global variable named `Debug`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DEBUG(level, fmt, ...) do if (Debug >= level) fprintf(stderr, fmt, __VA_ARGS__); while (0)

int Debug = 1; // default debug level == 1

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i1 = 1;
    int i2 = 2;

    size_t i;
    for(i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
        if ((argv[i][0] == '-') && (argv[i][1] == 'd'))
            Debug = strtol(argv[i] + 2, 0, 10);

    DEBUG(3, "process (%i, %i)\n", i1, i2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a great help. According to the content I am following, C programming by Stephen Kochan, one should be able to just do a.out -d1, -d2, -d3 and get different debug levels.